# Is there always a number $\leq n$ which is not divisible by primes $\leq \sqrt{n-1}$ for any $n$?

Tags: number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers

Let $n$ be a positive integer.

and let $p_1, p_2, ..., p_k$ be all the primes less than or equal to $\sqrt{n-1}$.

Then for each $i$, there exists approximately $[\frac{n}{p_i}]$ number of elements $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ which is divisible by $p_i$.

Extracting all such numbers gives us some numbers $\leq n$ which is not divisible by primes less than or equal to $\sqrt{n-1}$.

However, because $1$ is not divisible by any primes, if we want to find nontrivial numbers not divisible by such primes, then I think we should extract $1$ from the list of numbers.

So we consider $n-1 \gt [\frac{n}{p_1}]+\cdots+[\frac{n}{p_k}]$, 
but which is certainly not true, since we "extract" too many terms iteratively.

So I think we should consider
$n-1 \gt [\frac{n}{p_1}]+\cdots+[\frac{n}{p_k}]-([\frac{n}{p_1 p_2}]+\cdots+[\frac{n}{p_{k-1} p_k}])+\cdots+(-1)^{k+1}[\frac{n}{p_1 p_2 \cdots p_k}]$.

What I'd like to see is whether the above inequality always holds for any $n \gt 3$ or not.

Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Are you missing an assumption $n\le k$? (Otherwise $p_i$ for $1\le i\le n$ makes no sense if the primes only go up to $p_k$.)

Comment: @joriki Yes, It is miss-typo.

Comment: The title contains a completely different question than the text.

Comment: @joriki Is it? I thought that the inequlity tells us there exists a number which is not divisible by primes less than or equal to $\sqrt{n-1}$. Could you tell me what is different?

Comment: It seems to me that this is an easy consequence of Bertrand's postulate (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) ... as long as $2\sqrt{n-1}<n$, which is true for all but very few small $n$'s.

Comment: @StinkingBishop Oh, this is much more easy to see.. then it holds for $n \geq 3$?

Comment: So... are you asking is there always a prime between $\sqrt{n-1}$ and $n$?  I mean *all* numbers are divisible by primes (so your title makes no sense)

Comment: @fleablood Ah! I see. Sorry for my poor English writing. I’ll edit it now.

Comment: How do you feel about $n = 25$?  The number $5 < 25$ and $5$ is not divisible by any prime $\leq \sqrt{25-1}$.  This generalizes to any $n$ which is the square of a prime...  (Maybe I'm not getting what you're asking?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bertrand’s Postulate (a theorem) shows that for every $k\geq 2$, there is always a prime strictly between $k$ and $2k$.

Taking $k=\sqrt{n-1}$, if $2\leq 2\sqrt{n-1}\leq n$, then taking a prime $p$, $\sqrt{n-1}\lt p\lt 2\sqrt{n-1}\leq n$ will do, as $p$ is certainly not divisible by any prime smaller than itself.

If $2\sqrt{n-1}\gt n$, then $4n-4\gt n^2$, so $n^2-4n+4=(n-2)^2\lt 0$. As this never holds, you always have $2\sqrt{n-1}\leq n$.

So you just need to make sure $\sqrt{n-1}\geq 2$, which means $n\geq 5$. So the result certainly holds for $n\geq 5$. Then you just need to check it also holds for $n=1,2,3,4$. For $n=1$, you can take $1$. For $n=2$, you can take $n=2$. For $n=3$ you can take $3$. And for $n=4$, you can take $2$ (or $3$). So the result always holds.

Comment: It suffices that a prime $p$ satisfies $\sqrt {n-1}\le p\le n.$ Is there a simple proof of this without "Bertrand"?